# Rally SDK 2.0 Get data for random list of features

Tags: rally

I'm assembling a custom Rally app based on the SDK (v2).  I have a list of stories (stories that my team is doing on behalf of some other team) - and I want to get the PortfolioItem/feature to which those stories are parented.

Looking for ideas on the optimal (performance) way to approach that.  I suppose I could retrieve one feature at a time (how?) - though that causes network traffic per feature - but is there a way create a collection/model and fetch all the data in the collection at once?  (something like "get me all the features in my list of of featureIds").

TIA

Answer (score 0):

So first you'll start with getting the story model:

```
Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
    type: 'userstory',
    success: this._onStoryModelRetrieved,
    scope: this
});
```

And then with the model you can load individual stories like so:

```
_onStoryModelRetrieved: function(model) {
    model.load(storyOid, {
        fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Feature'],
        callback: this._onStoryLoaded,
        scope: this
    });
}
```

But you're right, there are perf issues with that.  So alternatively you can create a store and create an or'ed together filter query of objectid's:

```
var storyObjectIDs = [12345, 23456, 34567];

Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
    model: 'userstory'
    fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Feature'],
    filters: _.map(storyObjectIDs, function(storyOid) {
        return {
            property: 'ObjectID',
            value: storyOid
        };
    }),
    autoLoad: true,
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records) {
            //process records
        }
    }
});
```